# How can I simplify a nested php array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, nested

I'm writing a php web application where I have a nested array which looks similar to the following:

```
$results = array(
        array(
            array(
                'ID' => 1,
                'Name' => 'Hi'
            )
        ),
        array(
            array(
                'ID' => 2,
                'Name' => 'Hello'
            )
        ),
        array(
            array(
                'ID' => 3,
                'Name' => 'Hey'
            )
        )
    );
```

Currently this means that when I want to use the ID field I have to call `$results[0][0]['ID']` which is rather inefficient and with an array of over several hundred records becomes messy quickly. I would like to shrink the array down so that I can call `$results[0]['ID']` instead.

My understanding is that a function that uses a foreach loop to iterate through each row in the array and change the format would be the best way to go about changing the format of the `$results` array but I am struggling to understand what to do after the foreach loop has each initial array.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public function filterArray($results) {
    $outputArray = array();

    foreach ($results as $key => $row) {

    }

    return $outputArray;
}
```

Would anyone be able to suggest the most effective way to achieve what I am after?

Thanks :)

Comment: `$outputArray[] = $row[0];` in `foreach` ?

Comment: Can you show the code who generated this array ?

Comment: @Fky I'm developing with CakePHP 2.7 and that was the way CakePHP returned the array from a SQL procedure.

Comment: Ok use call_user_func_array http://php.net/manual/fr/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: im sure theres a way to modify the way your sql builds that result so that you dont have to deal with this. you should show us that code.

Comment: Maybe you can accept the answer of @Uchiha?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use [`call_user_func_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) as

```
$array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $results);
print_r($array);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/431649)

Comment: Well Thanks @splash58