# How to remove outer array in a multi-dimensional array in PHP and create a new array or make modifications in the same array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I've a multidimensional array titled `$event_details` as follows :

```
//Output of print_r($event_details);
Array
(
    [Today] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 439
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/439/winter-sprinkles-1/
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 503
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event                            
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/503/appcampusevent1/
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => Boxing Day
                    [event_id] => 504
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event                            
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/504/appcampusevent2/
                )
        )

    [Tomorrow] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => New Athletic Group
                    [event_id] => 505
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/505/sampleeve1/
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => New Athletic Group
                    [event_id] => 506
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/506/sampleevent2/
                )
        )

    [Thursday, January 7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => Boxing Day
                    [event_id] => 501
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event                            
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/501/demoevent5/
                )
        )

    [Saturday, January 9] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => Campusknot test
                    [event_id] => 431
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event                            
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/431/test-myevent/
                )
        )

    [Wednesday, January 13] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => Boxing Day
                    [event_id] => 500
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event
                        )

                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/500/demoevent5/
                )

        )

    [Friday, January 15] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => New Athletic Group
                    [event_id] => 498
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/498/demoevent2/
                )
        )

    [Wednesday, January 20] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 499
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/499/demoevent3/
                )
        )

    [Saturday, January 30] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => Campusknot Test Group
                    [event_id] => 473
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/473/test3/
                )
        )

    [Tuesday, February 16] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => Campusknot Test Group
                    [event_id] => 471
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/471/campusknot-b-039-day/
                )
        )
)
```

I want to remove the outermost array(i.e. first among the multidimensional array) and needs the final array exactly as below :

The second level array elements should come outside and the indexing should be from 0,1,2,3,....and so on.

You can do this thing to the same multi dimensional array `$event_details` or can create a new one as per the optimality and efficiency of the code.

```
Array
(
          [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 439
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/439/winter-sprinkles-1/
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 503
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event                            
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/503/appcampusevent1/
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => Boxing Day
                    [event_id] => 504
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event                            
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/504/appcampusevent2/
                )            

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => New Athletic Group
                    [event_id] => 505
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/505/sampleeve1/
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => New Athletic Group
                    [event_id] => 506
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/506/sampleevent2/
                )


            [5] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => Boxing Day
                    [event_id] => 501
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event                            
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/501/demoevent5/
                )


            [6] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => Campusknot test
                    [event_id] => 431
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event                            
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/431/test-myevent/
                )


            [7] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => Boxing Day
                    [event_id] => 500
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event
                        )

                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/500/demoevent5/
                )



            [8] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => New Athletic Group
                    [event_id] => 498
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/498/demoevent2/
                )


             [9] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 499
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/499/demoevent3/
                )


              [10] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => Campusknot Test Group
                    [event_id] => 473
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/473/test3/
                )


              [11] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => Campusknot Test Group
                    [event_id] => 471
                    [aFeed] => Array
                        (
                            [feed_display] => mini
                            [comment_type_id] => event
                        )
                    [url] => http://jumbo.com/event/471/campusknot-b-039-day/
                )            
)
```

Comment: Wont doing that loose some useful information about when these events takes place

Comment: @RiggsFolly:It will be fine for me even if the event information regarding the time vanishes from array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I simplify a nested php array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519715/how-can-i-simplify-a-nested-php-array)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `array_reduce()`

```
$result = array_reduce($event_details, 'array_merge', array());
```

Comment: This answer is working well, quick and neat to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily loop over your array with two loops and create a new array out of it. I would not bother manipulating the old array. Like so:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($event_details as $day) {
    foreach($day as $singleEntry) {
        $newArray[] = $singleEntry;
    }
}
```

The `$newArray` variable will afterwards contain the array you are looking for.

However, next time you ask a question, you should also include the things that you have already tried, or at least some approaches that you thought of but failed with, or something like that.

And P.S.: The indices will be increasing integers in your new array automatically, just like you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and recommendation but I haven't seen usage of any of the built-in array functions that are available in PHP.

Comment: Well there is no usage of it. Why would you need it? As you can see the task is pretty simple

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, couldn't a simple way like this will work? (untested)

```
$event_details = array (...);
$newArray = $event_details["today"];
```

Just simply copy the array from the point of entry `"today"` to the `$newArray`