# I want to merge these two arrays

Tags: php

I need some help in merging these two arrays.

```
$array = array(
  'a' => array('b', 'd', 'c'), 
  'b' => array('a', 'e', 'f')
);
```

I want my output to be like this (merged the two nested arrays above, then sorted)

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

What I have tried so far is this

```
foreach($array as $element=>$inner_element)
{
  $length = count($inner_element);
  for($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++)
  {
    echo $inner_element[$x];
    echo "<br>";
  }
}
```

This shows what the structure looks like, but I have no idea on how to proceed.

Comment: What the expected output should look like?

Comment: And what you have tried so far? And also post your expected output

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: As you're asking a question to developers and developers tend to (should) be picky on how you phrase things, let me be the one to point out there are three arrays there (yes, I do understand perfectly fine which arrays you are referring to, just show us that you try)

Comment: foreach($array as $element=>$inner_element)
{


 $length = count($inner_element);
 for($x = 0; $x <  $length; $x++) 
  {
        echo $inner_element[$x];
        echo "<br>";
  }

}

Comment: foreach($array as $element=>$inner_element)
{


 $length = count($inner_element);
 for($x = 0; $x <  $length; $x++) 
  {
        echo $inner_element[$x];
        echo "<br>";
  }

}

Comment: i want to get the values and sort them so that the output looks like this:a,b,c,d,e,f

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php merge  two arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561987/php-merge-two-arrays)

Comment: And also possible duplicate of [how-can-i-simplify-a-nested-php-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519715/how-can-i-simplify-a-nested-php-array/32519759#32519759) @BenRhys-Lewis

Comment: But the answer that OP is seeking over here perfectly matches mine @BenRhys-Lewis

Comment: Yeah. So why you say its a duplicate then. The question i linked is a duplicate of this question.

Comment: Not only are the answers different, the question is as well. The 2011 question merges two multi-dimensional arrays (preserving the inner indices), while the 2015 and this question don't.

Comment: and sorry everyone I am not lazy.its just i am new to php programming.

Comment: you can use RecursiveIteratorIterator

   

     <?php
        $a = array(
            'a' => array('b', 'd', 'c'), 
            'b' => array('a', 'e', 'f')
            );
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a));
        $out = array();
        foreach($iterator as $value) {
         $out[] = $value;
        }
        echo '<pre>'.print_r($out,true).'</pre>';
    
    /*output :
    Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => d
        [2] => c
        [3] => a
        [4] => e
        [5] => f
    )
    */
    
        ?>

Answer (score 1):

```
$result_array = array_merge($array['a'],$array['b']);
```

I am hoping you want to merge the arrays inside the main $array variable

Answer (score 1):

As the question appears to be lazy (it is actually harder to create a question here than it is to type the same thing into google), let me provide you with the answer that you wouldn't have found that way easily.

```
$array = array(
  'a' => array('b', 'c', 'd'),
  'b' => array('a', 'e', 'f')
);
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

This version allows you to merge whatever amount of arrays you have in `$array`.

---

The question has been extended with an additional desire to sort the output array. Just add the following to the code above:

```
sort($result);
```

Comment: Remove that `array_values` function from the code its creating an overhead over here

Comment: you are right, removed it

Comment: Good one +1 @RogierSpieker

Comment: you can use RecursiveIteratorIterator

   

     <?php
        $a = array(
            'a' => array('b', 'd', 'c'), 
            'b' => array('a', 'e', 'f')
            );
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a));
        $out = array();
        foreach($iterator as $value) {
         $out[] = $value;
        }
        echo '<pre>'.print_r($out,true).'</pre>';
    
    /*output :
    Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => d
        [2] => c
        [3] => a
        [4] => e
        [5] => f
    )
    */
    
        ?>

Comment: and here I was thinking my answer would be too complex for the question at hand ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way to merge two arrays:

```
<?php $newArray = $array1 + $array2; ?>
```

amaze